# Modules update failed

Tags: updating

I just tried to update some Modules on drupal 7 and got this:

> Update failed! See the log below for more information. Your site is still in maintenance mode.
>
> ckeditor
>
> ```
> Error installing / updating
> File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove file /home/myinvoice/public_html/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/dialog/dialogDefinition.js.
> ```
>
> imce
>
> ```
> Error installing / updating
> File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove file /home/myinvoice/public_html/sites/all/modules/imce/tpl/imce-file-list.tpl.php.
> ```
>
> menu_token
>
> ```
> Error installing / updating
> File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove file /home/myinvoice/public_html/sites/all/modules/menu_token/menu_token.module.
> ```
>
> recaptcha
>
> ```
> Error installing / updating
> File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot remove file /home/myinvoice/public_html/sites/all/modules/recaptcha/recaptcha.install.
> ```
>
> Next steps
>
> ```
> Your modules have been downloaded and updated. - DOES THIS MEAN THAT IT DID IN FACT WORK???
> Run database updates
> ```

Comment: Did you checked file permissions ?

Comment: I've Google the general error message here and there are a few answers on the front page.  I don't wish to appear rude, but may I suggest you do the same and then come back if the error persists :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site will most likely work, but with some bad luck the files could cause errors. The reason is either a file permission issue or, less likely, that you had the files open and that they were locked for that reason.

To be on the safe side you should manually update the affected modules, i.e. delete the directory and replace it with a downloaded copy. Then run the update script.

Do this for the affected ones:

- http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor
- http://drupal.org/project/imce
- http://drupal.org/project/menu_token
- http://drupal.org/project/recaptcha

Comment: Thanks @enzipher.

By running the update script you mean /update.php?

Doing an update crashed the whole site. Am now seeing the white screen :|

Will restore the db and redo the upgrade all over again.

Thanks for the tip re uploading the modules manually.

Comment: Yes, I meant `/update.php`. Sorry to hear about the issue, however, I don't see why reinstalling the modules wouldn't work, especially if you restore the db.

Comment: Thanks @enzipher.

I just uploaded the leatest versions of IMCE and Menu token modules, however doing an update.php gave me the following message:
No pending updates.

Does this mean that my update didn't work?

Comment: That means that there are no updates for any installed module. The updates that was available has already been executed. All should be good.

Comment: Thank you @enzipher
However, going to admin/reports/updates tells me that the modules I just updated ... there are updates available :S
shouldn't it automatically pick up that I've installed an updated? Or not?
I get why the Drupal core security update required is listed - because I haven't yet updated. But why the modules?

Comment: Also, the modules I just updates are still listed in: admin/reports/updates/update

Is this because I haven't done this step: http://drupal.org/files/upgrading-13.png

Comment: I should add that instead of DELETING the existing module folder I RENAMED it, in case I need to revert back. COuld this be why the updates aren't being picked up?

Comment: Renaming it won't work. At the very least move it to a location away from the Drupal installation. If you rename it the module is still taken into account. So delete or move the module's folder, and replace it with the new version and it should work.

Comment: perfection! @enzipher
It worked. Now to upgrade the core. Eeek

Comment: Same procedure. Basically delete everything except the `/sites` directory, copy the new files, run updates, and you're good.

Comment: Running this command solved it for me:
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/example.com/html/drupal` This might be a permission issue as @enzipher mentioned